# How to retrieve ancestor while chaining instances of classes

Tags: php, oop, chaining

I'm developping an application in PHP in which the ( jQuery-like) style of chaining methods is extremely convienent. I'm not talking about inheritance chains, but about a taxonomy of instances of classes that are 'embedded' inside each other. Now I wonder how I can refer to a higher level instance from a lower level.

This sounds all very abstract, so let me give an example. Let's say I want to write a book (proze) in PHP (just for the sake of arguement). It's very conveniently if I could code this like

```
$myBestseller = new Book();

$myBestseller
  ->setAuthor("Jean-Saul Partre")
   ->addChapter()
    ->addParagraph("How the Rabit lost its wings.")
        ->addWords("On a beautiful wintes day, the rabit flew over the … ") 
        ->addWords("Bla bla") 
        ->addWords("Bla bla");
```

So far, I got it working. (Should I include the actual class definions?) Now what if I would like to refer to a property of an object higher in the hierarchy? Let's say I'd like to include the name of the author in a the title of a chapter:

```
    $myBestseller = new Book();

    $myBestseller
      ->setAuthor("Jean-Saul Partre")
       ->addChapter()
        ->addParagrapWithAuthor("How "," fell out of the window.");
            ->addWords("Bla bla")
            ->addWords("Bla bla")
            ->addWords("Bla bla")

    var_dump($myBestseller);
```

Let's just add the Chapter class definition here as well:

```
class Chapter{
  private $_paragraphs = array();

  public function addParagraph($title){
    return $this->_pages[] = new Paragraph($title);
  }

  public function addParagrapWithAuthor($prefix, $suffix){
    $author = "Ideo Gram";
    return $this->_pages[] = new Paragraph($prefix.$author.$suffix);
  }
}
```

So, instead of ***$author = "Ideo Gram"*** I'd want to use the definition of the author of the book. The title with this code would be

> How Ideo Gram fell out of the window

Instead, I would like it to say

> How Jean-Saul Patre fell out of the window

Can this be done? The only solution so far I found is passing a reference to descendents 'under the table', but that feels like contaminating the classes.

Maybe the answer is very straight forward, but I can't find it. I might not know the right terms. ::parent, for example, works on extended classes.

Comment: If you need a bidirectionnal link between your entites, then keep a reference to the book in the author (you seems to already have the reference to the author from the book). This is the only way to do it.
If you don't define this relationship yourself, these entities will be totally unrelated to each others.

Comment: I am curious if using Variadic Function would also be of interest in this case. Let me know what you think: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function

Comment: @aguertin Interesting thought, thanks. Do you suggest passing the 'ancestry' through this Variadiac function? Like addCharacter('æ',$parent, $grandparent, $greatgrandparent, $greatgreatparent)? I'm surprised to read it can be done in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: @aguertin : nice thought. Yes it could work but I don't think it should be done in this use case. A chapter cannot exists if it is not linked to a book so the book can be an argument of the constructor (as a mandatory dependency). It seems to be the cleanest solution to me. There is nothing wrong or dirty in doing it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic. If you need a bidirectionnal relationship between 2 entities, they need to reference each other.

So your method `addChapter` could do this :

```
public function addChapter() {
    return $this->chapters[] = new Chapter($this);
}
```

So your chapter becomes :

```
class Chapter {

    protected $book;

    public function __construct(Book $book) {
        $this->book = $book;
    }

    ....

    public function addParagrapWithAuthor($prefix, $suffix){
        $author = $this->book->getAuthor()->getFullName();
        return $this->_pages[] = new Paragraph($prefix.$author.$suffix);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. This is what I meant with 'passing under the table'. In   my application this might mean passing the reference to the 'root' object 5 levels deep. From your answer and example I understand that this is completely acceptable. And that there is no magic method to make a descendent aware of its ancestry :)

Comment: I don't think it is "under the table" as you say. You can look at it as if a chapter cannot live if it is not owned by a book.

Comment: Indeed, it can not :)